# How to embed javascript in webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using WebView to load html pages but javascript is not working, I have done like this

```
WebView w=new WebView(this);
w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

w.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
setContentView(w);
```

Comment: webViewObj.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly enable javascript for this to work. Call setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: thanks for reply but still i m unable to do, please eleborate,

Answer (score 0):

What part the webpage javascript is not working? because there are functions like window.open which need other settings. like:

```
w.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```